# REST API JavaScript Reddit - search subreddit

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I am trying to create a web page where the user can type in a subreddit name and then the webpage returns data based on that webpage like the posts, or the name of the moderators etc..

I want to create a REST api in nodejs/express.

i have done a bit of research and i think i have to get the json data from the subreddit i want and then get the relevant data...

The part i am confused is how do i start? everything i see is got to do with python but i need to do it in nodejs.

Also wont the json keep changing format... for one subreddit it will be different to another subreddit

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you should check if theres an API for Reddit. Then when the user types in a subreddit, you would issue a GET request from your express route. The GET request would get the information from the Reddit API and send it back to the front.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.get('/api/subredditname', (req, res) => {
  //make your api request here, returning a promise hopefully
    //then send your data back
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data).status(200);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```